# SIGSEGV with SuperpoweredReverb

Tags: c++, android-ndk, superpowered

Does anybody know why I get a SIGSEGV as soons as the superpoweredReverb object gets deleted?

```
int size = 3056;
SuperpoweredReverb* superpoweredReverb = new SuperpoweredReverb(44100);
superpoweredReverb->enable(true);
float* buffer = new float[size * 2];
superpoweredReverb->process(buffer, buffer, size);
delete(superpoweredReverb); // <-- error SIGSEGV
delete[](buffer);
```

If size is 16, 32, 64 or 1024 all works fine. But by using other multiples of 8 like 1032, 2048 or 4096 I get the following error message:

- A/libc: invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x63647000 passed to dlfree
- A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 7148 (Thread-4888)

I am using the Superpowered SDK for offline processing with an android app. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: you know that your input buffer contains invalid floats do you? Not sure if it's the problem, but I would put some valid values in it.

Comment: Or `float* buffer = new float[size * 2] {};` to initialize the floats to 0. Or call `superpoweredReverb->process(nullptr, buffer, size)`

Comment: Also, is this your actual code or is this a pseudo-mockup of what your actual code does? I.e. does the problem actually manifest with the exact code posted?

Comment: Why all the usage of `new`, especially for things that absolutely do not need it, such as `SuperpoweredReverb`?  Looks like you're writing Java code, not C++.  `SuperpoweredReverb superpoweredReverb(44100);` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for your good hints but they did not solve the problem. When I don't use `new`/`delete` I get the same error as soon as the function returns. 
I have opened a new issue on github: https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/issues/168
The creators of the sdk might hopefully know it.
@kfsone: this is not my actual code but executing the sample code above leads to the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the sdk. Use buffer sizes <= 1024 for the SuperpoweredReverb until it gets fixed.
See https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/issues/168